# Why Do XML Entities Keep Literal Value in C# String?

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have an XML element with carriage return entities:

`<expectedValue>Success:&#13;&#10;Your Payment information has been updated!</expectedValue>`

I was expecting that when deserialized into an object with string property they would show as the C# escape characters such as:

`Success:\r\nYour Payment information has been updated!`

However the string still comes through with the literal entity values:

`Success:&#13;&#10;Your Payment information has been updated!`

Is there a way to have it deserialized as what I was expecting?

Comment: Usually this happens when xml is sent inside HTML body.  The HTML special character have to be encoded for the HTML layer to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [SecurityElement.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityelement.escape?view=netframework-4.8) there you see all letters that get encoded/decoded. if you further non xml encoded the data in the xml you have to decode it accordingly.